# Problems checking BTC current balance using blockchain.info's API, am I correct here?

Tags: api, blockchain.info, perl

I have a script that uses the Blockchain API to check the current balance on all my accounts one by one. When I reach a certain balance I sweep to a master account.

Am I using the correct code here as I am having errors checking the balance on accounts.

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->get("http://blockexplorer.com/q/getreceivedbyaddress/".$btcaddress);   # Check transactions on each address as per masterlist
my $getreceived = $mech->content;

$mech->get("http://blockexplorer.com/q/addressbalance/".$btcaddress);   # Check balance on of each address as per master list
my $addressbalance = $mech->content;
```

I can check transaction volume ok to reconcile with my accounts but I want to know the current final balance too so I can check that box also.

Comment: Looks fine. What specific error are you having?

Answer (score 1):

Just ran almost the exact same code in perl and this works:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use WWW::Mechanize;

my $btcaddress = "1Enn7YW22vBGvCWrsPQN7vDhnQCYhy221V";

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->get("http://blockexplorer.com/q/getreceivedbyaddress/" . $btcaddress);   # Check transactions on each address as per masterlist
my $getreceived = $mech->content;

print $getreceived . "\n";

$mech->get("http://blockexplorer.com/q/addressbalance/".$btcaddress);   # Check balance on of each address as per master list
my $addressbalance = $mech->content;

print $addressbalance . "\n";
```

Note the address is a random one I found on blockchain.info.